# Using Match/Case for dunder method __str__ to print correct value of a dataclass, is it possible?

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

I have a weird question. So im writing a dataclass called Row, if i wanted to allow for lambda values to be printed by the str dunder method, is this the correct way to implement that?
Am i wasting my time? is it already built-in?

```
    def __str__(self, value='all') -> str:
        xval = '__'
        aval = value
        try:
            named_value = self.column_names[aval]
        except:
            named_value = '__'
        
        match value:
            case 'values':
                return [x for x in self.value.values()]
            case 'all':
                return self.value
            case 'columns':
                return [x for x in self.value.keys()]
            case '__':
                return None
            case named_value:
                return self.values[named_value]
```

`

The syntax says that its okay. I dont have dataset yet. Was hoping some experienced in dataclasses and dunders could give me a helping hand?

Comment: What is happening when you try running this code now?

Comment: i didnt end up using it. Stuck with what i know. But it would be interesting to see implemented.